# Получение среднего размера экрана ПК-блокнотов для каждого производителя

Tags: sql

Здравствуйте, помогите плз, уже не лезет ничего в голову

Задание: 19 (обучение)
Для каждого производителя найдите средний размер экрана выпускаемых им ПК-блокнотов. Вывести: maker, средний размер экрана.

```
 select ol.maker, AVG(ol.screen) from 
(select pr.maker as maker, pr.model as model_1, l.model as model_2, l.screen as screen 
from laptop l, product pr
where pr.maker = 'A' and l.model = pr.model ) as OL
group by ol.maker
union all
select ol.maker, AVG(ol.screen) from 
(select pr.maker as maker, pr.model as model_1, l.model as model_2, l.screen as screen 
from laptop l, product pr
where pr.maker = 'B' and l.model = pr.model ) as OL
group by ol.maker
union all
select ol.maker, AVG(ol.screen) from 
(select pr.maker as maker, pr.model as model_1, l.model as model_2, l.screen as screen 
from laptop l, product pr
where pr.maker = 'C' and l.model = pr.model ) as OL
group by ol.maker
union all
select ol.maker, AVG(ol.screen) from 
(select pr.maker as maker, pr.model as model_1, l.model as model_2, l.screen as screen 
from laptop l, product pr
where pr.maker = 'D' and l.model = pr.model ) as OL
group by ol.maker
union all
select ol.maker, AVG(ol.screen) from 
(select pr.maker as maker, pr.model as model_1, l.model as model_2, l.screen as screen 
from laptop l, product pr
where pr.maker = 'E' and l.model = pr.model ) as OL
group by ol.maker
```

Ваш запрос вернул правильные данные на основной базе, но не прошел тест на проверочной базе.

- Неверное число записей (меньше на 4)

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону HAVING.

Comment: Я бы банил за такие вопросы, как всем сразу захотелось стать сертифицироваными с появлением hashcode.ru .

Или Вы думаете отвечающие здесь не понимают откуда вопросы?

Вы в сертификате будите указывать что работала группа профессионалов с hashcode.ru ?

Comment: Многоуважаемый SoftR, специально для ВАС:
...кто решил все рейтинговые упражнения до №64 включительно...
 Правила не нарушены, вы сначала читайте что написано вопрос 19(ОБУЧЕНИЕ), а потом говорите что то про Бан

Comment: @Михаил Матвеев повторю специально для Вас.
Я бы банил за то что просят помощи при попытке сертификации, хочешь иметь сертификацию учись, практикуйся и сдавай, а не шарься по всему интернету в поисках решения.
Мне на правила того ресурса глубоко наплевать, но мне как человеку имеющую не одну сертификацию по разным темам, глубоко не приятно что человек хочет получить корку (для удовлетворения своего эго) используя знания других.

Comment: SoftR мой вопрос который я задал не входит в те вопросы за которые дают сертификат, так что Ваше высказывание тут неуместно.

Comment: @SoftR, ну и че за троллинг? он задал вопрос, знаешь ответ - ответь, не знаешь не отвечай, все просто, а если с какой целью он просит ети ответы - тебе какое дело? пусть учится

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не поверите, это решение!

```
select maker, avg(screen) from product, laptop
where product.model = laptop.model
group by maker
```

Comment: Ну вот видите и незачем было постить все это и вашеть лапшу про "обучение"...

Comment: А, помнится, есть знак за ответ на свой вопрос)) Еще один голос и получится.

Comment: А что за знак?

Comment: Самоучка - Дан ответ на свой вопрос с 3 голосами за

Comment: спс) буду знать

Comment: так уж и быть =)

Comment: Дались всем вам эти очки.